# How to have ipad play different audio to that of a second screen connected by airplay in ios5?

Tags: audio, ios5, airplay, apple-tv

Is it possible to have the ipad play audio locally while at the same time playing different audio over airplay to a connected apple tv?

It IS possible to have the apple tv show different VIDEO to that shown on the ipad by initialising a second UIWindow for the second screen, but is it possible to do something similar with AUDIO? I can't even seem to get the ipad to play any sound at all while airplay streaming to my apple tv. Is it possible?